# Is "string-free coding" a common term?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Recently i get in touch with Empire-db. The project doc. stated that they are using "[string-free coding](http://incubator.apache.org/empire-db/empiredb/stringfree.htm)", intended to use less constant strings as possible to avoid typos and use the force of the compiler.

I was always a big fan of this principle, because i think as Java is a formal language it could be expresive for configuration like properties or xml and gives extra value by checking thru the compiler. Maybe at runtime there are less posibilities to changes without recompiling but this depends on each case.

Do you now more references or readings about this term/principle/design pattern ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Empire DB.  It is a tool which merits further intvestigation.  I was particularly struck by the analysis of Hibernate: http://incubator.apache.org/empire-db/empiredb/hibernate.htm

Comment: While it's a nice principle, as always, use common sense first. Mindlessly following a good design practice with good intentions can also lead to bad code, check out http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/It-Gets-Worse-Each-Year.aspx and http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Soft_Coding.aspx

Comment: Conversely, the anti-pattern is known as [stringly-typed](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped) code.

Answer (score 6):

This is the same thing as **magic number** vs **constants**. Using constants raises maintainability and readability. Constants also encapsulate change: a change in constant value is automatically propagated and, as for string-free coding, a misspelled constant is a compile-time error.

Answer (score 4):

I know little about Java, but this idiom is famous in modern C++. For example, [Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/xpressive.html) is a regular expression library that allows the programmer to write regex *in C++*, and does compile-time checking. [Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/index.html) is another example, where you could write EBNF *in C++*, and the compiler can check the syntax for you also :)

I think the *term* you are looking for is **Embedded Domain Specific Languages**.

Comment: Qt has something related too, but that's because of the way translations work there. Basically you encapsulate every user-visible string with "tr( ... )", and the app looks it up dynamically at runtime, only using the given string when no suitable translation was found.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard the particular expression, but [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) recommends to "*avoid strings where other types are more appropriate*" (Item 50).

Answer (score 0):

The famous [Pragmatic Programmer](http://www.pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer) mentions this principle especially in connection with metadata handling. One of the tips about this is:

> Put Abstractions in Code, Details in
> Metadata
>
> Program for the general case,
> and put the specifics outside the
> compiled code base.

It is worth reading the book anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding empire-db, it's like 'type-safety' for SQL queries.